# What are some tactile iPad apps to show to a graphic designer?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, applications

I'm looking for apps that have faux materials in them like leather, wood, paper, etc. (Apple stresses "tactile" apps when guiding developers.) I'm trying to guide a graphic designer. What are some apps that I can show that get the point across?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question didn't specify free apps so here are a few paid apps:

- [Manage](http://itunes.apple.com/app/manage/id384312640?mt=8) - currently $2.99 in AUD. Has a faux leather look.
- [Corkulous](http://itunes.apple.com/app/corkulous/id367779315?mt=8) - currently $4.99 in AUD. Simulates a corkboard complete with sticky-taped labels and sticky notes.
- [Ruler 2](http://itunes.apple.com/app/ruler-2/id374856771?mt=8) - currently $0.99 in AUD. Looks like a wooden ruler.
- [ABC News](http://itunes.apple.com/app/abc-news-for-ipad/id380520716?mt=8) - this one is free. It's not tactile, but the lead stories are presented wrapped around a globe.

There is a free app called [Stylapps](http://itunes.apple.com/app/stylapps/id444930066?mt=8) that is a showcase for stylish apps, though not specifically for apps that look like tactile materials.